# Back button title and arrow not on par

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, back-button

I have 2 connected viewcontrollers 
[image: img]

in storyboard and second controller has back button, but title and arrow situated not one level. I not programming anything in storyboard and sourcefiles.

[image]

Can i fix it in Interface Builder? Or programmatically?

Comment: If you are adding the button programmatically, the fix it programmatically and if so provide us with some code.

Comment: Ensure you had not typed enter after Back in text of your button

Comment: @SlavcoPetkovski no, i not added button programmatically, i have navigation controller, who has root controller is first view controller (left on 1st image) and second controller shows from it. (NavController --\--> 1st view controller --show--> second controller (image: http://i.imgur.com/qKYfmzn.png ) ). There is no any buttons in Navigation Items in this controllers in interface builder too.

Comment: Do you use custom navigation controller? Do you change its height or something else?